# Use static class and method instead of session in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

In my webapplication session is used in business layer, and this business layer (DLL) are used in mobile application. can i use static class and method to remove this session from business layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use static, users will override each others values. This is why Session State was created in the first place (in addition to caching etc....) as its isolated just for that specific user. using static in web is a bad bad idea especially when dealing with more than 1 user (the point on web app is to deal with multiple users at the same time too!)

also you say you are using Session in business logic? That doesn't sound right to me already... business layer should be completely separate and should not have access to Session since session is a web layer only accessibility. Seems like your architecture is also incorrect.

Comment: public static Dictionary<string, object> FlightDict; FlightDict.Add("I_ShoppingClient", client);  in this case user will override their values?are there any problem with that ?

Answer (score 1):

Storing data in static members instead of the session can produce very different results. The session in a web application is tied to the remote user through a session cookie. In other words, every user (with a different cookie) will have a separate session. The static members of a class, on the other hand, are the same for all the remote users of the web application. It gets more complicated if you consider web farms, web gardens and app domains but the general principle is the same.

If the data is unique to each user, the session (or some other place like the database) is the right place to store it. If the data is the same for all users then you might be OK using static members but watch out for issues when two or more users try to update the data concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

Better to inject the relevant fields you need from session into the business layer.